# Copying visual cells into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

In theory I can just use the specialcells method to copy visual cells after filtering into a new sheet, but I am getting an error:

```
MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AK$" & RowCountTotal).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy TemporaryWorksheet.Cells("A1")
```

How would I copy these visual cells in the masterlist into the temporary worksheet?

Comment: Run time error 5, invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: With the changes that Tim suggested, I am getting Run Time Error 1004, Select Method of Range class failed

Comment: [You should avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) but there's no way to help you further as it seems another line is throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells("A1")
```

should be

```
Range("A1")
```

or

```
Cells(1, "A")
```